# How to redirect the output of any command?

Tags: bash, ping, output

I'm trying to write a simple script to monitor my network status, without all of `ping`'s output:

```
ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null && echo online || echo offline
```

The problem is that when I'm not connected, I'm still getting an error message in my output:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
offline
```

How can I keep this error message out of my output?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you run:

```
ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null && echo online || echo offline
```

You are essentially only redirecting the output of Stream 1 (i.e. `stdout`) to `/dev/null`.

This is fine when you want to redirect the output that is produced by the normal execution of a program. However, in case you also wish to redirect the output caused by all the errors, warnings or failures, you should also redirect the `stderr` or Standard Error stream to `/dev/null`.

One way of doing this is prepending the number of the stream you wish to redirect to the redirection operator, `>` like this: `Command 2> /dev/null`

Hence, your command would look like:

```
ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2> /dev/null && echo online || echo offline
```

But, notice that we have already redirected one stream to `/dev/null`. Why not simply piggyback on the same redirection? Bash allows us to do this by specifying the stream number to which to redirect to. `2>&1`.

Notice the `&` character after the redirection operator. This tells the shell that what appears next is not a filename, but an identifier for the output stream.

```
ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1  echo online || echo offline
```

Be careful with the redirection operators, their order matters a lot. If you were to redirect in the wrong order, you'll end up with unexpected results.

Another way in which you can attain complete silence is by redirecting **all** output streams to `/dev/null` using this shortcut: `&>/dev/null` (or redirect to a log file with `&>/path/to/file.log`).

Hence, write your command as:

```
ping -q -c 1 google.com &> /dev/null && echo online || echo offline
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to redirect both standard output (`>` or `1>`) and standard error (`2>`):

```
ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>/dev/null && echo online || echo offline
```

or, redirect one to the other:

```
ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo online || echo offline
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$ ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo online || echo offline
```

#### Examples

```
$ ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo online || echo offline
online

$ ping -q -c 1 googleadf.com > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo online || echo offline
offline
```

#### Speeding up ping

Depending on your `ping` implementation you may be limited to a single count `-c 1`. Some implementations will let you go below this, but you're essentially having to wait for bad lookups to timeout. So instead of using `ping` you might want to use `fing` instead.

*slowness of ping failing*

```
$ date; ping -q -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo online || echo offline; date
Tue Jan 28 13:51:10 EST 2014
online
Tue Jan 28 13:51:10 EST 2014

$ date; ping -q -c 1 googleadf.com > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo online || echo offline; date
Tue Jan 28 13:51:15 EST 2014
offline
Tue Jan 28 13:51:25 EST 2014
```

*fing is much faster to fail*

```
$ date; fing -p google.com > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo online || echo offline; date
Tue Jan 28 13:49:21 EST 2014
online
Tue Jan 28 13:49:22 EST 2014

$ date; fing -p googleadf.com > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo online || echo offline; date
Tue Jan 28 13:49:35 EST 2014
online
Tue Jan 28 13:49:38 EST 2014
```

Comment: I'd rather use `time` command than manually computing time difference with `date`: `time { fing -p googleadf.com > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo online || echo offline; }`

Comment: @Ruslan - thanks, I did it this way b/c I wanted the output of `date`. It's easier, IMO, for someone else to read the output generated.