# Internet connection drop alert

Tags: networking, audio, monitoring

What software is there that will play an alert (PC speaker) when there isn't any internet connectivity for 5 minutes?

My switch/router seems to disconnect every few days, and I want to reset it when it happens.

```
PC          -- TP-Link switch/router -- FO
192.168.x.1 -- 192.168.x.2 / x.y.z.a -- a.b.c.d
```

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but you're taking a very roundabout solution to the problem of a faulty switch/router

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a modified version of this script to do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

downTime=0
lastAccessTime=$(date +"%s")
while [ true ]; do
if ! ping -c1 google.com >& /dev/null; then
    downTime=$(( $(date +"%s") - $lastAccessTime ))
else
    downTime=0
    lastAccessTime=$(date +"%s")
fi

sleep 15

if [ $downTime -ge 300 ]; then
   echo "alert"
fi
done
```

#### We're "CONNECTED" Example

With debugging turned on so you can see what the script's doing.

```
set -x
```

Running with a valid hostname to demonstrate the "connection is up" state.

```
$ ./watcher.bash
+ downTime=0
++ date +%s
+ lastAccessTime=1402276955
+ '[' true ']'
```

The above initializes a couple of variables and determines the last time we went through the loop, `$lastAccessTime`. We now try to ping Google.

```
+ ping -c1 google.com
+ downTime=0
++ date +%s
+ lastAccessTime=1402276955
```

We now calculate any down time, `$downTime`, if ping fails, otherwise, we reset `$downTime` to zero, and recalculate `$lastAccessTime`.

```
+ sleep 15
```

Now we wait 15 seconds.

```
+ '[' 0 -ge 300 ']'
```

Now we check if we've been down for > 5 minutes (300 seconds). Then we repeat going through the `while` loop.

```
+ '[' true ']'
+ ping -c1 google.com
+ downTime=0
++ date +%s
+ lastAccessTime=1402276970
+ sleep 15
....
```

As long as we're up, nothing will happen other than we check with the `ping` command every 15 seconds.

#### We're "DISCONNECTED" Example

Now to simulate a "connection is down" state, we'll swap out the hostname we're pinging and use a fake one, `google1234567890.com`. Repeating a run of our script with debugging enabled we now see some actual down time getting calculated.

```
$ ./watcher.bash
+ downTime=0
++ date +%s
+ lastAccessTime=1402277506
+ '[' true ']'
+ ping -c1 google1234567890.com
++ date +%s
+ downTime=0
+ sleep 15
+ '[' 0 -ge 300 ']'
+ '[' true ']'
+ ping -c1 google1234567890.com
++ date +%s
+ downTime=15
+ sleep 15
...
```

Notice above that `$downTime` is equal to 15 seconds so far. If we wait a while longer we'll see this:

```
+ '[' true ']'
+ ping -c1 google1234567890.com
++ date +%s
+ downTime=300
+ sleep 15
```

We've accrued 300 seconds of down time. So now when we check, we print the message, `alert`.

```
+ '[' 300 -ge 300 ']'
+ echo alert
alert
+ '[' true ']'
+ ping -c1 google1234567890.com
++ date +%s
+ downTime=315
+ sleep 15
```

This state will continue until the connection is restored and the `ping` is once again successful.

#### So what about a sound?

That's easy. You can use a variety of tools to do this. I would use something like `sox` or `mplayer` to play an audio file such as an `.mp3` or `.wav` file with an appropriate sound you want to hear every 15 seconds, while the connection is down.

```
mplayer someaudio.wav
```

Simply replace the `alert` message above with this line to get audio feedback that the connection is down.

#### Timing out issues with ping

If you use `ping` in the manner above you'll likely encounter a slow lag time where it takes `ping` literally 10-20 seconds for it to fail when the connection is down. See my answer to this U&L Q&A titled: [How to redirect the output of any command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111357/7453) for an example using the command line tool `fing` instead. This tool will fail more quickly than the traditional `ping`.

Comment: Btw I'm using `beep` command, is it safe to `chown /dev/tty0` so I could use it without `sudo`?

Comment: @Kokizzu - no you shouldn't be changing the ownership on `/dev/tty0`.

Comment: Hooray, `sox`! @Kokizzu - slm's right about leaving the permissions on the `/dev/tty0` device alone, but you could get a *pseudo-terminal* `/dev/pts/[num]` device - the same kind of character device that `xterm` uses for each window, for example - with something like `screen` or `tmux` or even `ssh`. These you can more safely control as they're only slave devices to the master `/dev/ptmx` device anyway and won't cause the same kind of problems as, say, a user-owned `/bin/login` process might - which is what could happen in the other case.

Comment: `aplay alert.wav` is a more standard way to play sound as it's part of the ALSA system and comes prebundled in most distros.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Linux you can use ping within a script to `google.com` for example:

```
counter=0
while [ true ]
do
ping -c 1 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
then
    let "counter +=1"
else
    let "counter = 0"
fi
if [ $counter -eq 300 ] # we assume that one ping need one second (300 is 5 minutes)
then
   echo "alert"
fi
done
```

Comment: This will work, but you might want to consider using `fing` instead of `ping`. The `ping` cmd. can take a bit to fail when it isn't successful. The `fing` command on the otherhand will fail within 1 second. See my A to this Q&A for more: [How to redirect the output of any command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111357/7453). I show both using `ping` and `fing`.

Comment: @slm, Thanks for your editing, I was confused how to make ping last only for one second

Comment: It seems this will execute ping an unlimited number of times per second if it responds immediately, such as when the ethernet loses power. `sleep 1` is enough to prevent this.